# Laravel Query Builder wherebetween

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, query-builder

I build a search form which will select markers from database where date is inserted in datapicker. That works fine but , when I add time I get error .

I rebuilded a query to something like that :

```
$datefrom = $request->input('datefrom');
$dateto = $request->input('dateto');
$timefrom = $request->input('timefrom');
$timfrom = $timefrom.':00';
$timeto = $request -> input('timeto');
$timto = $timeto.':00';
$type = $request->input('type');

$maps = Map::select('lat','lng',$type,'temp','humidity','date','time')
                ->where(function($query){
                    $query->whereBetween('date',array($datefrom,$dateto))
                    ->whereBetween('time',array($timfrom,$timto));
                })
                ->get();
```

When I enter check on search form I get error :

> Undefined variable : $datefrom etc.

Any help ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've to pass it to the function using `use` like :

```
->where(function($query) use ($datefrom){
     $query->whereBetween('date',array($datefrom,$dateto))
           ->whereBetween('time',array($timfrom,$timto));
})
```

If you've more than one you could pass them like :

```
->where(function($query) use ($datefrom,$dateto,$timfrom,$timto){
     $query->whereBetween('date',array($datefrom,$dateto))
           ->whereBetween('time',array($timfrom,$timto));
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That works but , timfrom must be lower then timto even dateto is bigger then datefrom. How to change it that it will works for example if we get : from 2016-04-04 15:45  to 2016-04-08 12:12

Comment: Not sure what you mean @Egzan :( but i think that is another nice question to post separately, i think the problem in the OP _Undefined variable : $datefrom etc._ was solved by this post if true you could **[accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** and go ahead to post another with new more detailed description.. good luck.